# C#/C++ -> How to log, which programs are run by user

Tags: c#, c++, windows

I want to log the whole list programs started by user,

e.g.

chrome.exe @ time1

explorer.exe @ time2

wmp.exe @ time3

It is similar to how process lasso logs the whole thing in Action window,

can anybody help me over this.

Edit : 
Forgot to mention platform, it's Windows

Comment: you'll probably have to write a driver

Comment: Why did you use both C++ and C# tags? Which language will you use for this? Keep only one.

Comment: @Axalo not at all, Win32 APIs will do the job.

Comment: @PranitKothari,

can you elaborate?

Comment: @Pranit then please explain how

Comment: @Axalo There are Win32 APIs which gives process information. I do not have complete answer to this question, otherwise I could have posted it.

Comment: @Axalo There are actually several means: [tool help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684887.aspx), [PSAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682623.aspx), [WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394372%28VS.85%29.aspx)... but this question is unanswerable until the OP picks a language.

Comment: @Pranit I suppose you're talking about comparing process snapshots?

Comment: @Axalo no we can get all the running processes in system. Even we can get for new processes. But do not know exact step and solution.

Comment: @Pranit I'm talking about [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682623(v=vs.85).aspx). still, that's not what the OP wants since he wants to get notified when a process starts.

Comment: @Axalo Exactly that is what I mean too. And notify work will be done by WMI. I think [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12138/Process-Information-and-Notifications-using-WMI) should help.